# Oracle SQL: how do you duplicate a row and modify some of the values in a statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL: how do you duplicate a row and modify some of the values in a statement? there's around 50 columns

I was thinking of copying a row into a temp table
modify the values in the temp table
insert into existing table

But I was wondering if there's a better way

Comment: insert into TableName(*)
   select col5='New', col10='New', ...
   from TableName;

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t (col1, col2, col3, . . .)
    select col1, <whatever expression you want>, col3, . . . 
    from t
    where . . . ;
```

Comment: but there's 50 columns, is it possible to modify the data for only 2 columns? I don't want to type all the 50 column down.

Comment: @BTree . . . Typing the 50 columns isn't that hard.  You can always insert the row as a duplicate and then update it later -- assuming there is some sort of auto-generated id.

Comment: I was thinking of referring to the newly created row as rownum=count(*) + 1? i need to check how to store variables

there isn't auto-generated id

Comment: I'm a believer that you should always list out the columns. You never know when someone else is going to come along and change the column order or something. I have cases where a development and production database have columns in different orders.